# GSON parsing nested JSON objects differently depending on the environnement

Tags: android, json, parsing, nested, gson

I have a nested JSON object, for example :

```
{
    "references": [
      "CONTRACT", 
      "DURATION", 
      "EDUCATIONLEVEL", 
      "EXPERIENCELEVEL", 
      "LANGUAGELEVEL", 
      "CIVILITY", 
      "AVAILABILITY"
    ], 
    "unavailablenetworks": [
      {
        "content": "Service unavailable", 
        "id": "100"
      }, 
      {
        "content": "Service unavailable", 
        "id": "200"
      }
    ], 
    "urls": {
      "apiurl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxx", 
      "base": "https://yyyyyyyyyyyyyy", 
      "video": "https://zzzzzzzzzzzzz"
    }
}
```

and the following Java classes :

```
public class Version implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("references")
    private List<String> references;

    @SerializedName("unavailablenetworks")
    private List<UnavailableNetwork> unavailableNetworks;

    @SerializedName("urls")
    private BKUrls urls;
} 

public class BKUrls implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("apiurl")
    private String api;

    @SerializedName("base")
    private String base;

    @SerializedName("video")
    private String video;

    @SerializedName("edition")
    private String edition;

    @SerializedName("offer")
    private String offer;

    @SerializedName("search")
    private String search;
}

public class UnavailableNetwork implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("content")
    private String content;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
}
```

Getter and Setter methods are omitted here to simplify reading.

I use GSON to parse the JSON :

```
Gson g = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
Version version = g.fromJson(json.toString(), Version.class);
```

This code is using in an Android application that I'm developping.

If I install and run the application on an Android Smartphone in debug mode using Android Studio, `Gson` parses the Json Object correctly.

But If I try to generate an `apk` and then, install that apk on the same smartphone, `Gson` does not parse the JSON entirely. The result is like this :

```
{
    "references": [
      "CONTRACT", 
      "DURATION", 
      "EDUCATIONLEVEL", 
      "EXPERIENCELEVEL", 
      "LANGUAGELEVEL", 
      "CIVILITY", 
      "AVAILABILITY"
    ], 
    "unavailablenetworks": [
      {
        "id": "100"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "200"
      }
    ], 
    "urls": {
    }
}
```

"references" is ok

"unavailablenetworks" is incomplete, missing "content" field

"urls" is empty

I don't understand why Gson doesn't work the same ? Why some data are missing using apk while using Android Studio in debug mode all data are ok ?

Comment: Only a guess, but could it be that ProGuard (or a similar code shrinking tool) removed some of the fields from the classes because it thought they were unused?

Comment: Well, I think it's a good idea to explore. Any idea to change this ? Is there any settings inside ProGuard for that ?

Comment: @Marcono1234, I confirm the issue was caused by ProGuard. Exactly it was the `minifyEnabled` option sets to true. I added some `keep` options and now it seems to be alright. Thx for your help.